# Display recent wp blog posts on website

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to load the most recent posts of a wp blog on cms page (magento).
This is the code I've got in my block, which is then called on the cms page:

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<div class="wpTest">
<?php
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>    
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<?php
endforeach;
?>

</div>
```

Now when I load the homepage there is no error or anything, but it doesn't show the blog posts. Can anybody spot a mistake in the code or have any idea where I could look for the issue?